# Segmentation fault while declaring an iterator in c++ example of leveldb

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault, leveldb, sstream

I was trying to apply an iteration to my leveldb file, but unfortunately I couldn't get the result. The problem that I'm facing is a segmentation fault in using the pointer of the iterator. I used gdb And I got that the problem is in the line

```
leveldb::Iterator* it = db->NewIterator(leveldb::ReadOptions());
```

(I added before some values to this file /tem/userDb , and the add is working good .)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <leveldb/db.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void iteration(leveldb::DB* db)
{
    leveldb::Iterator* it = db->NewIterator(leveldb::ReadOptions());
    for (it->SeekToFirst(); it->Valid(); it->Next())
    {
        cout << "key :" << it->key().ToString() << " : "
             << "value:" << it - > value().ToString() << endl;
    }
    if (false == it->status().ok())
    {
        cerr << "An error was found during the scan" << endl;
        cerr << it->status().ToString() << endl;
    }
    delete it;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    leveldb::DB* db;
    leveldb::Options options;

    options.create_if_missing = true;

    // erase error if the database exists
    options.error_if_exists = true;
    leveldb::Status s = leveldb::DB::Open(options, "/tmp/userDb", &db);
    if (!s.ok()) 
        cerr << s.ToString() << endl;
    iteration(db);
    delete db;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain `db` is not `NULL` after the call to `leveldb::DB::Open`?

Comment: actually I just discovered that its NULL , but I dont know why because the file is physically existing in my /tmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with the `leveldb` API, but you're using `db` regardless of whether `s.ok()` is `true` or `false`. I'd assume that if `s.ok()` is `false`, `db` is either `NULL`, or in a state such that iteration or other operations won't work.

You should change the code to:

```
if (!s.ok()) {
    cerr << s.ToString() << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: actually you are right , after adding that return -1 , I didnt got the error of segmentation fault  but got this "Invalid argument: /tmp/userDb: exists (error_if_exists is true)
", because its clear that the programm ended in the return -1 , what can be the cause in your opinion sir ?I dont understand why the pointer of the db is not working while its physically existing in my folders

Comment: @MadHer -- Wouldn't the API you're using have a function to return more information as to the error?  An API just returning `true` or `false` wouldn't sound robust -- there should be an additional function you would call to get more information once you get a failure return value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually there is not , else than s.ToString , what I know is that the problem is with the db because its existing , when you use for the first time there is no prblm ( creation time ), when you try to open it and to apply some updates its not working anymore

Comment: @MadHer the message has all  seems it's complaining that the database already exists. It does so because `options.error_if_exists` is set to `true`. Set it to `false` if it makes sense and won't overwrite it.

Comment: @HoriaComan I set it to false , and actually guess its working because no more error about db existence , thanks for the help , I will update it more